# Is there a symbol for "less than, equal to, or greater than"?

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to find a symbol for "less than, equal to, or greater than" similar to this:

[image]

I have not been able to find one. If anyone knows of such a command, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: In similar cases you can use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html - draw your desired symbol and it tries to recognize it. Your case: `\usepackage{ amssymb }
\lesseqqgtr` :)

Comment: What's the use-case? :D

Comment: Makes no sense to me as it indicates that there is no relationship between the numerical values.

Comment: @PeterWilson mathematical theoreticists will have their use-case for such a hell-born symbol. As a non-mathematician, I don't question their methods. As long as a math's doctor came up with the symbol, I imagine there _is_ indeed a use for it.

Comment: @thymaro I'm not a mathematician as my father told me that the UK only needed five and I was not one of them, so I became an engineer. He was happy with answers involving integrals and Greek and Russian letters but I needed numbers.

Comment: @PeterWilson in a partial order (or preorder), that symbol indicates that there is some order relationship between two elements: one of them is less than or equal to the other, without necessarily knowing which one is which . The negation of that symbol indicates that two elements are unrelated in the order, i.e. that neither is less than or equal to the other.

Answer (score 16):

Here are the possibilities with `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[ A\gtreqqless B, \quad A\lesseqqgtr B\]%
\[ A\gtreqless B\quad A\lesseqgtr B\]%
\[ A\gtrless B\quad A\lessgtr B\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here are two possibilities using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage{amssymb}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \centering

    $\theta_{nc}^D < \theta^D$\\
    $\theta_{nc}^D > \theta^D$\\
    $\theta_{nc}^D = \theta^D$\\
    $\theta_{nc}^D \leq \theta^D$\\
    $\theta_{nc}^D \geq \theta^D$\\ 

    $\theta_{nc}^D\lesseqqgtr \theta^D$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There seems to be no real need for `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.